# I want to replace "-" for "\" but it doesn't work as I expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I have a md file named "2021-05-06.md".
I tried to make the name of the file "2021/05/06.md" by using Python Library "os".

```py
i="2021-05-06.md"
os.rename(i,i.replace("-","/"))
```

Actually, the code above is just a example but I get the Error telling "Path not found".
It seems like the "/" are recognized as a part of path.
How should I avoid this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advise against trying to use slashes in your filename for many reasons.

If you would rather disregard this advice then you might be able to use the unicode divison slash character (u"\u2215").

```
i="2021-05-06.md"
os.rename(i,i.replace("-",u"\u2215"))
```

Whether or not this works may depend on operating system.

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2215/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
import os  
filepath="your file path"
r=filepath.repalce('-','/')
os.rename(filepath,r)
```